# Select only the second preceding tag if there is one, or then just the first one

Tags: xpath

I have this HTML:

```html
<h4>block 1</h4>
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<table></table>

<h4>block 2</h4>
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<table></table>
```

As you can see, the first block contains two `<p></p>` tags, while the second block only has one.

I am currently using this XPath: `//table/preceding::p[1]`, which [returns](http://xpather.com/):

```
1. <p>paragraph 2</p>
2. <p>paragraph 1</p>
```

However, this is what I'd like to have:

```
1. <p>paragraph 1</p>
2. <p>paragraph 1</p>
```

So basically the farest "preceding" table `p` tag, as explained in my question title.

I want to keep using `//table/preceding`, as this is very important in my case.

I already tried `//table/preceding::p[1 or 2]`, but that selects both.
I also tried `//table/preceding::p[2]` but that will select both paragraphs from the first block, and none from the second one.

As you can probably notice, I'm pretty new to XPath. How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Your current and desired outputs are the same. Please update your question

Comment: @DonnyFlaw Done, sorry about that.

Comment: Can you also add parent node (nodes) tags? It's not clear whether table nodes are siblings or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one to get select desired paragraphs

```
//table/preceding-sibling::h4[1]/following-sibling::p[1]
```